# Python - "while not var"

Tags: python, while-loop

I've been reading "Automate the Boring Stuff" and trying to learn Python basics. They give example code in the book and I usually expand on it a bit to further understanding/refresh previous material. In these examples; I've come across a concept I don't quite understand.

No matter what I enter for `name`, I cannot get past the loop and on to the guests portion of the program. I would really appreciate if someone could explain this command and tell me how to break free from the name portion and on to the guests portion.

```
name = ""   #defines var, blank string boolean equiv = "False"
while not name:        #Start loop and checks... something??
    print('Enter your name:')
    name = input()    #Loop repeats no matter what I enter here..
print('How many guests will you have?')
numOfGuests = int(input())
if numOfGuests:
    print('Be sure to have enough room for all your guests.')
print('Done')
```

Comment: What is this code *supposed* to do?

Comment: Hmm, works for me. When I just press `enter` it loops back to `Enter your name:`, but if I enter a character, then press `enter` it goes onto the next part.

Comment: This works as expected. I enter a name and then the next prompt shows up after pressing Enter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with the code. This was the output for me:

```
Enter your name:
How many guests will you have?
Be sure to have enough room for all your guests.
Done
```

Empty strings in Python are evaluated as false, so the use of 'not' make it true; therefore, you get in the loop, and until you've not entered anything, you're still in the loop. After you enter something, you get out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
while True:
    if name == "":
        name = input("what is your name ? ")
    else:
        break
```